# Ti-Nspire programming: How to store the output (answer) with multiple results in separated variables?

Tags: ti-nspire

I'm trying to store the results of this expression in separate variables, but I didn't reach success:

solve([[ω₃][ω₄]]=k^(−1)*(ω1*[[−l1*sin(θ1)][l1*cos(θ1)]]+ω2*[[l2*sin(θ2)][−l2*cos(θ2)]]),ω₃,ω₄) ▸ (ω₃=−4.02989 and ω₄=−0.709524)

I'd like to store ω₃ and ω₄ in separetade variables.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution by writing the command as shown:

ω₃₄:=exp▶list(solve([[ω₃][ω₄]]=k^(−1)*(ω1*[[−l1*sin(θ1)][l1*cos(θ1)]]+ω2*[[l2*sin(θ2)][−l2*cos(θ2)]]),ω₃,ω₄),{ω₃,ω₄}) ▸ [−4.02989,−0.709524]

ω3:=ω₃₄[1,1] ▸ −4.02989
ω4:=ω₃₄[1,2] ▸ −0.709524